# Bootstrap datetimepicker z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Estoy abriendo un datetimepicker en un modal pero al abrir el picker queda detrás:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he puesto la propiedad z-index en el css pero no me funciona.

```
 <div class="form-group is-empty">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="t_ejecucion">Tiempo ejecución: </label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="input-group date">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t_ejecucion"
                                               style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


$('#t_ejecucion').datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT'
        })
```

Estoy usando https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ que incluye https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js a parte de bootstrap y jquery.

Comment: @x-rw Si pero aun asi utilizando el !important no me funciona

Comment: se me hace que tu modal esta mal construido, revisalo

Answer (score 1):

Si estás incluyendo los estilos del datepicker después de los estilos de bootstrap (que es como supongo que lo estás haciendo) entonces lo que te faltaría sería darle una propiedad background-color al elemento, más que modificar el zIndex.

**Edit**: ahora entiendo que el recuadro no es el borde del datepicker sino que lo has puesto tú (doh!).

El zIndex del modal no tiene cómo superponerse al título si no tiene la propiedad `position` puesta en `relative` o `absolute` y está contenida en un elemento que a su vez tenga esa propiedad.

En tu caso, habría que darle `position: relative` y zIndex al formulario que contiene al modal.

Si eso no resulta, revisa en chrome devtools exactamente a qué contenedor se añade el modal, y juega con el position y zIndex de ese contenedor. La idea es que todo lo que sobresalga del contenedor tenga mayor zIndex que el título.

Si eso no resulta, puede que sea simplemente que tu contenedor (en este caso el formulario) tiene la propiedad `overflow` seteada en `hidden` por lo cual oculta cualquier parte que sobresalga de él. A partir de tu imagen, no podría decir si es esto lo que ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no incluiste la propiedad:

`position:absolute` en tus estilos

Para que el div quede libre y se pueda superposiciones con `z-index: +1`

Claro que después tendrás que posicionar tu div, por que al realizar la posición absoluta, el div quedará flotando y tendrás que agregar restricciones de posición.